# which version of sqoop to download

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I have installed hadoop 2.2 version and want to have some experiemnt with apache-sqoop.

Can anyone guide me please which sqoop version to use ? Please also send the official getting started guide for installation and usage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can install sqoop-1.4.4 version in hadoop-2.2,

```
http://apache.osuosl.org/sqoop/1.4.4/
```

Step 1 : Extract the tarball.

Step 2 : Rename file to sqoop.

Step 3 : set the class path in .bashrc and compile it using `$source .bashrc`.

Step 4 : Also set hadoop home path.

Step 5 : Now check the sqoop installation using `$sqoop help`

if you want to import or export data from sqlserver or oracle database you need to add `sqlserver connector jar file` and `oracle connector jar file`.